# Зачем здесь обрабатывать ошибку SystemExit

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

SystemExit обрабатывает ошибку, которую вызывает sys.exit(). То есть, по идее, без вызова функции exit() этой ошибки не будет. Я делаю телеграм бота, использую вот этот шаблон https://github.com/Tishka17/tgbot_template/blob/master/src/tgbot/cli.py, в котором встречается except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit). Зачем нужно обрабатывать SystemExit, если он все равно не прилетает? Могу предположить, что systemd когда останавливает *.service вызывает в программе SystemExit. Хотелось бы понять почему и получить best practice — почему не написать просто except, ловя все ошибки, хоть и нужно ловить только одну по pep? Ведь остановка бота может быть спровоцирована не только этими ошибками

Comment: Ловить все ошибки абсолютно точно плохая практика, потому что это может привести к потере информации о возникшей ошибке, из-за чего можно её случайно вообще не заметить; если уж вы собрались ловить все ошибки — обязательно запишите traceback пойманной ошибки в лог, чтобы информация не потерялась. Ну а SystemExit наверное ловится просто для соблюдения общепринятой практики, потому что это стандартный способ завершения работы python-программы

Comment: @andreymal а почему это общепринятый способ завершения работы? Обычно же завершается какой-то ошибкой или стандартным KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Функция [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) выбрасывает именно SystemExit

Comment: @andreymal это я понимаю, только смысл обрабатывать ошибку, которую сам вызываешь? Типа, в этом шаблоне же sys.exit() я никогда сам не вызову из-за ненадобности, соответственно обработчик не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Хотелось бы понять почему и получить best practice — почему не написать просто except, ловя все ошибки, хоть и нужно ловить только одну по pep?

```
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        logger.error("Bot stopped!")
```

Ну вот смотрите - в данном куске кода проверяется, что было "легальное" завершение работы бота - он был прерван с клавиатуры, либо сам для себя вызвал выход через `sys.exit`. И об этом пишется в лог. Вы потом открываете лог, смотрите - ага, в такое-то время бот был остановлен по такой-то причине. Удобно.

> Зачем нужно обрабатывать SystemExit, если он все равно не прилетает?

Ну, это диалектический вопрос. С одной стороны, промышленное программирование учит нас не делать лишних фич, которые нам не нужны в данный момент. Но в данном случае это ведь шаблон, универсальная заготовка. Откуда шаблону знать - есть конкретно в вашем боте использование `sys.exit` или нет? Да и вы на самом деле не можете быть на 100% уверены, что у вас он не появится в коде когда-нибудь. И тогда вы с одной стороны вроде бы сможете залогировать это событие там, где вы собственно вызываете `sys.exit`. Но что если такое место будет не одно? Удобно ведь сделать логирование не во всех местах, где вызывается `sys.exit`, а только в одном, по принципу `DRY`. И вот это и есть то самое место, где это лучше всего сделать.

> Хотелось бы понять почему и получить best practice — почему не написать просто except, ловя все ошибки, хоть и нужно ловить только одну по pep? Ведь остановка бота может быть спровоцирована не только этими ошибками

Вот именно поэтому и не рекомендуется ловить все исключения без разбору. Вы предлагали бы написать так?

```
    except Exception:
        logger.error("Bot stopped!")
```

Но тогда вы не узнаете, какая именно ошибка произошла и не сможете её потом починить. Ваш бот будет внезапно останавливаться, а вы даже и не узнаете причину этого.

Можно, конечно, логировать любые ошибки:

```
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("Произошла какая-то ошибка!", ex)
```

Но тогда в случаях, когда бот был остановлен через Ctrl+C или через ваш же `sys.exit`, в лог будет писаться совершенно лишняя информация. Такая остановка не является ошибкой, зачем вам лишняя информация, забивающая лог и отвлекающая ваше внимание? Потом вы захотите найти по логу поиском, не было ли ошибок, будете там находить вот эти записи и пытаться понять - ошибка ли это или нормальное завершение. Зачем вам лишняя ручная работа?

Так что **best practice** тут будет такая - **добавить** здесь или где-то уровнем выше (если он у вас есть) обработчик всех исключений, но сделать это **не вместо** обработки конкретных исключений, а **в дополнение** к ним:

```
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        logger.error("Bot stopped!")
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("Произошла какая-то ошибка!", ex)
```

После этого вы легко сможете найти в логе реальные ошибки, требующие вашего вмешательства, просто поиском по слову "ошибка". Удобно.